# Go: Get strings between two strings (markers), with potentially nested instances of markers

Tags: go

I'm fairly new to Go and have been trying to figure out how to get the (sub)strings between two strings or markers. The start of the block I want to capture will start with the format *"MARKER MARKERNAME"* (where *MARKERNAME* ***can*** be unique, but doesn't have to be) and always end with "*ENDMARKER*" There can potentially be multiple instances of nested sub-markers within the text block. For example:

```
MARKER BOB
    BOB_LINE1
    BOB_LINE2
    BOB_LINE3
    MARKER SALLY
        SALLY_LINE1
        SALLY_LINE2
        SALLY_LINE3
    ENDMARKER
    MARKER JUNE
        JUNE_LINE1
        JUNE_LINE2
        JUNE_LINE3
    ENDMARKER
    BOB_LINE4
    BOB_LINE5
ENDMARKER
```

I found the following code that works for a single instance of looking for the strings between two strings, but it doesn't work when I have nested instances of markers.

```
func GetStringInBetweenTwoString(str string, startS string, endS string) (result string, found bool) {
    s := strings.Index(str, startS)
    if s == -1 {
        return result, false
    }
    newS := str[s+len(startS):]
    e := strings.Index(newS, endS)
    if e == -1 {
        return result, false
    }
    result = newS[:e]
    return result, true
}
```

Ultimately, I would like to read these into a data structure like a map, but the other wrinkle is that the *MARKERNAME* is not guaranteed to be unique, meaning I could have another block of text later that starts with the marker name of *BOB* (or *SALLY*, etc..). For example:

```
MARKER BOB
    BOB_LINE1
    BOB_LINE2
    BOB_LINE3
    MARKER SALLY
        SALLY_LINE1
        SALLY_LINE2
        SALLY_LINE3
    ENDMARKER
    MARKER JUNE
        JUNE_LINE1
        JUNE_LINE2
        JUNE_LINE3
    ENDMARKER
    BOB_LINE4
    BOB_LINE5
ENDMARKER

MARKER BOB
    BOB_LINE6
    BOB_LINE7
    BOB_LINE8
    MARKER TED
        TED_LINE1
        TED_LINE2
        TED_LINE3
    ENDMARKER
    MARKER BILL
        BILL_LINE1
        BILL_LINE2
        BILL_LINE3
    ENDMARKER
    BOB_LINE9
    BOB_LINE10
ENDMARKER
```

The user will determine which blocks of text need to be processed by passing in arguments. In the example above, if the user had passed in "*BOB, JUNE, TED*" I would want the following blocks of text:

```
BOB_LINE1
BOB_LINE2
BOB_LINE3
BOB_LINE4
BOB_LINE5
BOB_LINE6
BOB_LINE7
BOB_LINE8
BOB_LINE9
BOB_LINE10
JUNE_1
JUNE_2
JUNE_3
TED_1
TED_2
TED_3
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: You should recursively parse the string into a tree-like data structure, rather than trying to accomplish this with simple string searching.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://go.dev/play/p/v8quSpOBDI-). Depending on your desired result, just parse the `MARKER` pair correctly. So append to the stack on `MARKER`, pop on `ENDMARKER`. Lookup lines using the current top of the stack.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I just realized my data is a bit more complex to parse, but I think this sits me on the right path.